# spark.driver.cores setting in spark standalone cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark Standalone cluster mode and use `"spark.driver.cores"` to set number of cores for the driver. But every time the UI shows it "0" as shown in the picture [image]

Even setting up this value in the code

```
.set("spark.driver.cores","14")
```

does not seem to work. How should this value be set in the standalone cluster mode ?

Thanks
**===UPDATE===**
Here is the spark-submit command

```
        spark-submit --jars "file:///<path to jar>" --master spark://$MASTER:7077 --conf "spark.cores.max=330" 
    --conf "spark.executor.core=5" 
    --conf "spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=10000000" 
    --conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000" 
    --conf "spark.default.parallelism=1000"  
    --conf "spark.executor.memory=40g"  
    --conf "spark.driver.memory=40g" 
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseCompressedOops -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" 
    --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=40g" 
--conf "spark.network.timeout=10000000" 
--class "<my class>" "<path to jar>" <other parameters>....
```

Each of the node in the cluster has 24 core and 64GB memory. 
I hope this helps. Thanks for your help.

Comment: show your  spark-submit are you overriding somewhere ?

Comment: use '--conf "spark.executor.cores=5"` as in the [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior)

Answer (score 4):

```
`--conf "spark.executor.core=5"` is wrong
```

should be (s is missing)

```
--conf "spark.executor.cores=5"
```

second thing is if  you are not setting [`spark.driver.cores`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) is spark-submit.

your `.set("spark.driver.cores","14")` should be like

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
 .set("spark.driver.cores", "2")
   .setAppName(this.getClass.getSimpleName)
   .setMaster("local[*]")

   val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).appName(this.getClass.getName)
   .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

> Tip :  To Verify what cofigurations you are applying : 
>   `spark.sparkContext.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)` will print all the configurations applied to create the spark session.

In the above example :

```
(spark.app.name,com.examples.DataFrameCSVExample$)
(spark.app.id,local-1558579973832)
(spark.driver.cores,2)
(spark.master,local[*])
(spark.executor.id,driver)
(spark.driver.host,192.168.19.1)
(spark.driver.port,53962)
```

If you are able to see here, spark-ui should show the same...

Hope you understood!!!

Comment: did you try aforementioned way ?

Comment: looks like i hit the enter at the wrong place...here is my original reply .   "Thanks for pointing out the typo in "core(s)" .    But the "local[*]" runs the spark job in local mode whereas i want to run it in a cluster. taking clue from your suggestion, i even used <master>[*] but the UI still shows driver cores as "0" as shown in the screen shot above. Thanks for your help."

Comment: What is the right way to use * if i am setting master as "--master spark://$MASTER:7077"   . I do it this way because i use SLURM to submit my job and have no control over the selection of master node. Thanks

Comment: i dont know SLURM  but `./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]` is standard way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193856/discussion-between-sumit-purohit-and-ram-ghadiyaram).

Comment: sorry @Ram I am still looking for the solution in standalone cluster mode.